# modificar proyecto laravel copiado desde otra pc

Tags: php, laravel

primero que nada, soy nuevo en php, y en laravel.

Copié un proyecto laravel, no desde ningun repositorio, y me corre perfectamente con xampp.
ahora quiero modificar ese proyecto, quiero saber si tengo que instalar o midificar algo.

Comment: ¿Intentaste algo? ¿Falló algo?

Answer (score 0):

Ahora que lo tiene en otra computadora segun entiendo, tiene que ejecutar enla terminar dentro de tu proyecto

composer dump-autoload 
php artisan config:cache 
php artisan view:clear 
php artisan clear

y darle permisos a las carpetas storage y bootstrap
en MAC, seria

sudo chmod -R 777 storage 
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap 
sudo chmod -R 777 public

En windows tendrias que ingresar a la carpeta dentro' del proyecto click derecho y propiedades luego te vas a permisos y le das todos los permisos a las carpetas que te menciono

Comment: Por favor evitemos responder a preguntas mal planteadas y que es casi seguro terminen cerradas, gracias por el aporte

Comment: Mal planteada o no, muchas veces se puede comprender lo que dice, no esta de mas ayudar a todos, basta con tratar de comprender, pero ok no respondere!